# How to sync the read history of Gnus between computers through Dropbox?

Tags: gnus

I try to read email and mail list with Gnus on different computer. I am able to sync the configure files through Dropbox and it works fine.

But I don't know how to sync the read history. I am always get the read articles show as unread on different computers repeatedly.

Comment: I sync my Emacs *everything* to all computers, so I never have to worry about syncing a single component.  That might be the simplest thing you could do in this situation.

Comment: I don't think that gnus actually tracks this information by itself.  You may have to synchronise your mail storage itself.

Answer (score 0):

#### Required reading

See the Gnus Manual node on [Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Startup-Files.html). This mentions the various files and related settings that Gnus uses to save information such as ranges of read/unread articles per group. I believe configuring and syncing these files in addition to your `gnus-init-file` will solve your problem. I think the main files are located at `~/.newsrc` (cross-newsreader) and `~/.newsrc.eld` (Gnus-specific) by default, but I'm not 100% certain.

#### Recommended reading

Gnus in Emacs 25.1 comes with a new feature called the [Gnus Cloud](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/The-Gnus-Cloud.html), which uses an IMAP server to synchronise your Gnus data across machines.

You may also be interested in this [EmacsWiki article on syncing Gnus](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusSync).

#### See also

Documentation of variables:

- `gnus-home-directory`
- `gnus-directory`
- `gnus-article-save-directory`
- `gnus-startup-file`
- `gnus-read-newsrc-file`
- `gnus-save-newsrc-file`

For more peace of mind, also read documentation of variables:

- `gnus-backup-startup-file`
- `gnus-use-dribble-file`
- `gnus-dribble-directory`
- `gnus-always-read-dribble-file`

Comment: I found the Gnus Cloud documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/draft/manual/html_node/gnus/The-Gnus-Cloud.html  I don't know why it's only available in the draft subdirectory.

Comment: Updated link to Gnus Cloud https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/The-Gnus-Cloud.html